# Was wiki software inspired by version-control systems?

Tags: version-control, wiki

Because I am interested in the history of software too:

Wikis and VC software have some things in common - they store text (mostly); all versions of a specific text are stored forever; you always know who made which change at what time; and you can restore the old versions too if you want.

But VC is much older than wikis. So I was wondering: Did the first wiki developers get their inspiration for the wikis from VC software? In the history of WP I couldn't find anything.